# Is it safe to walk around with the Square Filter and Holder in? Not in tripod

Tags: filters

I read this really terrific Q&A about them: [Screw-in or square filters in the field?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/screw-in-or-square-filters-in-the-field)

I really want to get an ND filter because of how versatile it would be but think I'd rather get the Square style. I currently only have a screw-in Polarizer filter and I hate using it. I don't like the feel of it at all. The effect is so-so but the mechanics of it just aren't enjoyable.

So I'm looking at getting the square filter style instead. My main concern is can you walk around with these filters attached? Say I just want to use a subtle ND or Graduated ND to be able to open the aperture up while doing street photography in harsh sunlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can you walk around with these filters attached?

I don't know how much the Cokin holder grips the filter. I have the Lee system, and from the standpoint the filter holder gripping the filter, I would have every confidence in walking around with the filter in place. I would have no fear that the filter would slip out.

*However*, other than briefly moving to another spot, I wouldn't be walking around, run-and-gun ready-to-shoot style, leaving the filter on. The reason is that a rectangular GND presents so many opportunities for snagging and catching on things. Plus, with a 100mm × 150mm area (4" × 6"), that's a lot of opportunities to scratch a resin filter.

The Lee filter holder snaps onto the lens adapter *very* quickly and easily, without looking. Indeed, it goes on so easy (and comes off easy), I'd be afraid of the spring loaded filter holder release handle snagging on clothing, letting the holder and filter fly off the lens, before I'd ever worry about the filter slipping out of the holder.

I carry a filter pouch (the [Lowepro 100](http://store.lowepro.com/s-f-filter-pouch-100)) with the GND pre-inserted into the holder. That way, I can quickly grab the filter + holder combo from the pouch and slap it on the lens in a few short seconds.